# golang type mismatch when using inherited struct

Tags: go, mgo

```
    type MongoDBConfig struct {
    *mgo.DialInfo
}

func ConfigureMongoDB() (*MongoDBConfig, error) {
    //Get gopath

    GOPATH := os.Getenv("GOPATH")

    file, err := os.Open(GOPATH+RESOURCE_PATH)

    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    decoder := json.NewDecoder(file)

    mongoConfig := MongoDBConfig{}

    er := decoder.Decode(&mongoConfig)

    if er != nil {
        return nil, er
    }
    return &mongoConfig, nil
}

func InitMongoDB() (*Session, error){

    mongoConfig, err := ConfigureMongoDB()

    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    session, mongoerr := mgo.DialWithInfo(mongoConfig)

}
```

Getting error in the last line while passing mongoConfig. I created the struct type of MongoDBConfig using DialInfo type.

> Cannot use mongoConfig (type * MongoDBConfig) as type *DialInfo

Comment: In Go you can't **inherit** stuff a la classical OOP. What you have there is an **embedded** type. https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#embedding

Comment: I missed this earlier. Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Access embeded field explicitly:

```
 session, mongoerr := mgo.DialWithInfo(mongoConfig.DialInfo)
```

Comment: A conversion is not needed, just call the embedded struct by `mgo.DialWithInfo(mongoConfig.DialInfo)`

Comment: @Vadyus you can't convert the embedding type `MongoDBConfig` into the embedded type `mgo.DialInfo`. Your code example is not even gonna compile.